# c# How to cast a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I want to cast a dictionary so that the values are cast as an interface that is implemented by the original type;

first of all:

```
public class DataRef<T> : IRef
{
      public int ID;
      public static Dictionary<int, T> LookUp = new Dictionary<int, T>();
}

public class Terrain : IThing
{
    ///IThing
    public ImageRef DefaultImageRef { get { return defaultImageRef; } }
    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    public string name = "unamed Terrain";

    //Other Stuff
    public TerrainType TerrainType = TerrainType.Floor;
    public ImageRef defaultImageRef = new ImageRef(typeof(Terrain));
    public ImageRef alternateImageRef = new ImageRef(typeof(Terrain));
    public int imageRef2;
}

public interface IThing
{
    ImageRef DefaultImageRef { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

This expression does not compile:

```
(Dictionary<int,IThing>)DataRef<Terrain>.LookUp
```

Error:

> Error 15  Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary< int,MO1.Definitions.Terrain >'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary< int,MO1.Definitions.IThing >' C:\Projects\MO1RPG\VSsolution\Editor\Main.cs    28  72  Editor

I want to cast the dictionary because I want to use it as a parameter that is cast as "Dictionary" Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with casting. You must create a new dictionary.

It's unintuitive at first, since you can do this:

```
Terrain dataRef = new Terrain();
IThing thing = (IThing)dataRef;
```

But you're not allowed to do this:

```
Dictionary<string, Terrain> dict = new Dictionary<string, Terrain>();
Dictionary<string, IThing> castDict = (Dictionary<string, IThing>)dict;
```

The difference is explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

To put it simply, though, a Dictionary is not read-only, and thus cannot provide certain guarantees required to perform the cast. For example

```
Dictionary<string, Terrain> dict = new Dictionary<string, Terrain>();
Dictionary<string, IThing> castDict = (Dictionary<string, IThing>)dict;
castDict.Add("Rob", new DifferentThing()); // DifferentThing implements IThing
```

What we've done here is added a `DifferentThing` to a dictionary which expects `Terrain`, which is a big no-no. Why is it a big no-no?

Because what if someone then does this: `Terrain terr = dict["Rob"];`
Now we're trying to store a `DifferentThing` into a `Terrain`

What you need to keep in mind is casting an object is *not* (with exceptions, of course) creating a new object, but rather, changing how we view it externally.

In order to have a `Dictionary<string, IThing>` from a `Dictionary<string, Terrain>`, you would need to create a *new* dictionary defined as `Dictionary<string, IThing>` and fill it with the original dictionary.

See BrianMains' answer for the way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the Cast Linq method, but you may need to instead use the generic `ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => (IThing)v.Value);` option instead.